# Can't seem to get list() working

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, list

I am trying to convert a set object to list...for example "p=list('abc')" is not working.
any ideas or is it inherent in appengine

Comment: What does "Not Working" mean?  Can you provide some specific bad behavior?  An error traceback is nice.  Some other incorrect behavior is helpful.

Comment: my aim was to do something like: 
##code fragment
objCategory=set(re.split('^\s*|\s*,*\s*|\s*$', objCategory))
cr=2
p=list('abc')##this ain't working
cr=1
## with this i'll expect to get cr=1 in my list of local variables in django debug output.but it stays as 1. Please pardon if it may seem roundabout, but i am a newbie to python and appengine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A set object to list is converted like so:

```
my_list = list(my_set)
```

I don't understand your example though. Converting a string to a list results in a list of characters:

```
>>> list('abc')
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

if the list() command is not working for you, you could work around it like this:

```
my_list = []
for item in my_set:
  my_list.append(item)
```

hth

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific change "inherent" in appengine with respect to common aspects like lists. It is as just the same, plain python.